# Order of imported modules overwrite the injected abstraction into module

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, abstract-class, abstract

I have a `TableComponent` which need an abstract service to do some asynchronous calls. The module looks like:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
    ],
    declarations: [
        TableComponent
    ],
    exports: [
        TableComponent
    ]
})
export class TableModule {

    static forRoot(tableService: Type<TableService>): ModuleWithProviders {
        return {
            ngModule: TableModule,
            providers: [
                { provide: TableService, useClass: tableService }
            ]
        };
    }
}
```

and I have to module further: EmployeeModule and LocalizationModule. It both looks:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        TableModule.forRoot(EmployeeTableService), <---- Injected EmployeeTableService
    ],
    declarations: [
        EmployeeComponent,
        ModalEmployeeComponent
    ],
    providers: [
        EmployeeResource,
        EmployeeRepository,
        EmployeeTableService
    ]
})
export class EmployeeModule {
}

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        TableModule.forRoot(LocalizationTableService),
    ],
    declarations: [
        LocalizationComponent
    ],
    providers: [
        LocalizationResource,
        LocalizationRepository,
        LocalizationTableService
    ],
})
export class LocalizationModule {
}
```

And now I import those two modules into AppModule in **order.**. So it looks like:

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        AppRoutes,
        LocalizationModule,
        EmployeeModule
    ],
    providers: [
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

The problem here is an order. Depends on which module (Employee or Localizations) is last that service is injected into `TableComponent`, which takes abstraction as param of constructor. Ie. if the order is like above only `EmployeeTableService` is injected. Otherwise `LocalizationTableService` is injected - why and how to change it so the `TableComponent` will take always the right abstraction?

The `TableComponent` looks like:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'sp-table[configuration]',
    templateUrl: './TableComponent.html',
    styleUrls: ['./TableComponent.scss'],
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class TableComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(
        public readonly dialog: MatDialog,
        private readonly tableService: TableService,
        private readonly changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef
    ) {
        super();
    }
```

Example of EmployeeTableService:

```
@Injectable()
export class EmployeeTableService extends TableService {
    constructor(
        private readonly employeeResource: EmployeeResource
    ) {
        super();
    }

}
```

Comment: It's correct behavior in angular di system. You assign different providers to the same injection token and register it in the root injector via importing `EmployeeModule` and `LocalizationModule` into `AppModule`. Ok, then in the `TableComponent` you inject `TableService` and expect it to be what? How to understand what is **right abstraction** in this case?

Comment: It depends on module which import table module. If localization imports table module and provide localization table service then localization table service should be provided into table component. If employee service then employee service

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly here is [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jovqvm)

---

The reason why the one provider overrides another in this case is the way you are defining them. When you define provider via `providers` array of a module it will be registered in the root injector. So the only one solution I know is to override `TableService` on the component level every time you are going to use it. Also you may define *default* provider for `TableService` in root injector for cases where you want to use the `TableService` directly.

Comment: why is it necessary to override service on the component level instead of module level?

Comment: Because every provider declared in module (not lazy) registered in root injector. We can limiting providers scope only by lazy modules (they have own injector) and components (providers, viewProviders). [doc](https://angular.io/guide/providers#providing-dependencies-in-modules)